# Is it possible to use the LIKE statement in inside BETWEEN statement?

Tags: mysql, select, between, sql-like

Here's the thing, im trying to list a bunch of reports in a specific range, the tricky part is that we have 12 different kind of reports, so i need to be able to list EVERY report of that range.

Let me explain it with an example:

```
type 1 =RR10000
type 2 =TT10000
type 3 =HH10000
```

if i list 10000 to 10005:

```
RR10001
TT10001
HH10001
RR10002
TT10002
HH10002
RR10003
TT10003
HH10003
RR10004
TT10004
HH10004
RR10005
TT10005
HH10005
```

Is there any way to do this? any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your types are always 2 characters followed by digits, then you could just extract the digits and do a `between` on those:

```
... WHERE SUBSTR(yourfield, 2) BETWEEN 10001 AND 10005
      AND SUSBSTR(yourfield, 0, 2) IN ('RR', 'HH', 'TT')
```

won't be particulary efficient, since you can't use indexes for this kind of thing. If you need to do this on a "large" number of records, consider splitting this type field into a composite field (chars,digits), then you can trivially do a `between` on the digits field.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do regex matching, here's the reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html.

However, if your case is that simple, something like  @MarcB's answer should suffice (was about it to write it out as well).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RLIKE` which is a regex match.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    someColumn LIKE '^(RR|TT|HH)1000[0-5]$'
```